# Is this integral beyond the scope of Mathematica's calculations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I can't get the correct result when calculating the integral as below, could you please help me to see where I am wrong?

```
R[x_] := Subscript[\[Rho], 
  s]/((x^\[Beta] + (Subscript[r, c])^\[Beta])^(1/\[Beta])/Subscript[r,
    s]*(1 + x/Subscript[r, s])^2);



Integrate[R[x]*x^2, {x, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {Subscript[r, c] > 0, Subscript[r, s] > 0, Subscript[\[Rho], s] > 0, t > 0, x \[Element] Reals}]
```

The expression of R[r] is shown in the follow figure
[image]

Comment: Suggest you first integrate it with values assigned to the constants and if integratable,begin replacing the values with symbols one by one and re-integrate.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. You have overloaded the integral by unnecessary details, while there are some missing assumptions. One finds the core expression for the integral which can be transformed to

```
Integrate[(a + x)^(-1/b)/(1 + x)^2*x^2, {x, 0, t}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, t > 0, x > 0, b < 1}]
```

[image]

Analogously one gets the result provided b>1. Then, however, the integral exists if a>1.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this simplified R[r] seems to deviate a lot from my R[r]. This seems far from what I'm dealing with.

Comment: To make the remark of @sfks clearer, you probably need `a + x^b` instead of `a + x` to be able to transform back to the OP's integral.

Answer (score 4):

It does not look like this is integrable.

To help find why and where, you can use `Rubi` package. It will integrate the parts it can, and leave the parts that can not be integrated.  Also, start with indefinite integral. Almost all integrals that can't not be solved as indefinite can not be solved as definite (but there are few exceptions due to some tricks depending on the specific case).

```
Quit[]
R=ρ/((x^β+rc^β)^(1/β)/rs*(1+x/rs)^2);
Integrate[R*x^2, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using Rubi:

```
<< Rubi`
Int[R*x^2, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we see that the part that can't be integrated is

```
 Integrate[(rc^β+x^β)^(-1/β)/(rs+x),x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The problem is with the exponents `-1/β`

As mentioned now in comment, for `β=1` or `β=-1` it can. But not for general `β`. Even assuming `β` is integer did not help. So for your original integral, if you set
`β` to one of these values it will solve it.

```
R=ρ/((x^β+rc^β)^(1/β)/rs*(1+x/rs)^2);
Integrate[R*x^2/.β->1,x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
R=ρ/((x^β+rc^β)^(1/β)/rs*(1+x/rs)^2);
Integrate[R*x^2,x,Assumptions->Element[β,Integers]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At least now you know why/where it is stuck and why it can't solve it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is true that only when beta takes the value of juti can it be integrated.：）